# Compare two data Structure and Suggest the best match

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, compare, maps

Hi all I have two structure that is `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`.The first Map structure is a hospitals preferences example `<Hospital name,<Student,Preferences>>`.
The second map is a student preferences example `<Student,<Hospital,Preferences>>`.
How can I compare both and find the Best matches according to given Preference.

Find the data below
First map

```
{St. Luke's={ Martin Fowler= 2,  Alan Turing= 1}, Olathe Medical Center={ Martin Fowler= 2,  Alan Turing= 1}}
```

Second Map

```
{Martin Fowler={ Olathe Medical Center= 1,  St. Luke's= 2}, Alan Turing={ Olathe Medical Center= 1,  St. Luke's= 2}, ï»¿Martin Fowler={ Olathe Medical Center= 1,  St. Luke's= 2}}
```

Code for creating this  structure is

```
    public Map<String,Map<String,String>> readingFile(String filename) {
    Map<String,String> preference = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> DataPreference = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    CSVReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String[] line;
            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                preference.put(line[1], line[2]);
                DataPreference.put(line[0], preference);
            }
            System.out.println(DataPreference);
        }
        catch (IOException |ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         System.out.println("File empty or File not fond in the given Path ");
     }
    return DataPreference;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post what (code) you've tried so far. At least put the code for creation of these Maps and your attempt to iterate over them.

Comment: what should be the logic to find the "best match"? in your example input, what should be the output and why?

Comment: • If a hospital and student favor each other the most, they should be matched unless no other match is possible.
• If a hospital and student despise each other the most, they should not be matched unless no other match is possible. 
• If perfect matches are not possible, hospitals should be matched to the student that is the best fit.
• The end goal is that for every match, it wasn’t possible to form a better match for all parties involved @Kartik

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This problem is a variant of [stable marriage problem / stable matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) , i.e, with unequal size and polygamy allowed :)

The algorithm works by a number of *rounds*. The hospital matches the student according to its preference. The student then reviews the proposals, tentatively holds on to the best proposal and rejects the rest.  In the next round, the rejected hospitals propose to their next best choice, and the students again retain the best proposal and reject the rest. This process continues until there are no more students left to propose.

The principle used is **deferred acceptance**

http://www.nrmp.org/matching-algorithm/